# How to aggregate street lines using value filter

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, expression, aggregate, qgis-expression

I have a shapefile of a service done on a street. This service has a sequence of execution and whether or not I should run on that street (blue and red). At each corner of the street I'm working on, I have the street before and after **(image 1)**. However, I need to synthesize and add the values ​​of the street I am working on, following the execution sequence, taking into account the first and last streets **(image 2)**.
How can I do this? Whether using some tool or some expression.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Português:** Eu tenho uma shapefile de um serviço feito em uma rua. Esse serviço tem uma sequência de execução e se eu devo ou não executar naquela rua (azul e vermelho). A cada esquina da rua que estou trabalhando, eu tenho a rua anterior e a posterior (imagem 1). Contudo, eu preciso sintetizar e agregar os valores da rua que estou tranbalhando, seguindo a sequencia de execução, levando-se em conta a primeira  e a última rua (imagem 2).
Alguém pode me ajudar nisso? Seja usando alguma ferramenta ou alguma expressão.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few steps of analysis going on here, but if you are willing to try Virtual Layers, you could do it all in one hit.

Here is a solution (major tip courtesy of [this answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41949823/11418874) to generate an incremented `dense_rank()` even with duplicated values as used in subquery `t` below).

---

To use the query, go to Layers > Add Layers > Add/Edit Virtual Layer and in the window paste the query below, replacing the layer name (`streets`) and column names (`seq`, `street_nam`, `street_fir`, `street_las`, `mode`) as required.

Virtual Layers can be slow on large datasets. This query could be further optimised but in any case I would recommend once your virtual layer is generated, save it as another file rather than leave it visible.

---

```sql
WITH t
     AS (SELECT *,
                CASE
                  WHEN street_nam = lag(street_nam) OVER (ORDER BY seq)
                       AND mode = lag(mode) OVER (ORDER BY seq) THEN 0
                  ELSE 1
                END AS x
         FROM   streets),
     p
     AS (SELECT *,
                SUM(x) OVER (ORDER BY seq) AS rank
         FROM   t),
     g
     AS (SELECT geometry,
                rank,
                street_nam,
                first_value(street_fir) OVER (PARTITION BY rank ORDER BY seq)
                   AS fv,
                last_value(street_las) OVER (PARTITION BY rank ORDER BY seq 
                   RANGE BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND unbounded following) 
                   AS lv,
                mode
         FROM   p)
SELECT st_linemerge(st_collect(geometry)) AS geometry,
       rank                               AS seq_new,
       street_nam,
       fv,
       lv,
       mode
FROM   g
GROUP  BY rank
```

---

## Example and explanation

### Sample data

[image]

### Step 1 (subquery t)

This sets up the next query with a temporary column `x` so that we can generate a rank that increments based on

a. whether `street_nam` has changed from one row to the next along the initial sequence (so it doesn't matter if the same value appears again later in the sequence), and

b. whether `mode` has changed from one row to the next along the initial sequence.

Interim result:

[image]

### Step 2 (subquery p)

Generates `rank` as required using a cumulative sum and `x`. This sets up groups that we can use at the end.

Interim result:

[image]

### Step 3 (subquery g)

Extracts the first and last value based on `rank` groups from step 2.

[image]

### Step 4 - final query

Finally, we aggregate the data - group by the generated `rank`, and collect + merge the linestring geometries accordingly. This is the final output you see when using the query above.

Geometry result:

[image]

Attribute table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*First of all thank you very much. You helped a lot.*

How do I do it when the shapefile has more than one route? (image 1)

Attention: each route has its own sequence and starts at 1, but ends at different values.

Example:

[image]
[image]

**Final result**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry I only saw your follow up question 8 months later. On StackExchange you need to update your question rather than post your follow up as an answer, and comment on the answer to notify the answerer that you have edited your question, otherwise your follow up question can get ignored... I believe you can use the same query as above but for subquery g just add this line before mode: `route`, and change the last line of the query to `GROUP BY route, rank` - don't have the data on hand to test again but it should work. If you found the original answer useful please mark it as accepted.